# Linprog Python - Implementing binary numbers

Tags: python, optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have multiple constraints and they are straight forward to enter in linprog, but I have two constraints that has a binary component in them. Following is the one:

1 or 0 is Nabc

Mabc - 11(1) <= 0    <-- M111 - 11(1)
or
Mabc - 11(0) <= 0    <-- M111 - 11(0)

abc are subscripts

How do I implement this in linprog module or possibly make it such that binary is not required.

Here is the one that I can implement in python because there is no binary number associated with it:

Mabc <= 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy's linprog only solves Linear-programming problems.

Your problem is not an LP, but an Mixed-integer problem (MIP) and thus cannot be solved (no Branch-and-Bound or Branch-and-Cut code available there).

I don't get your example, but it is very very likely that it cannot be solved without Binary/Integer variables.

You can try [pulp](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) which would be the easiest approach getting a MIP-ready lib which supports formulation & solving (e.g. CBC and GLPK; CBC is automatically linked on at least the windows-install).